# Does Google Earth Engine have InSAR Processing Capabilities for Sentinel-1 data?

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-1, insar

I am attempting to find an easier way to work with InSAR data (i.e. getting land movement data). I have worked with SARProz and SNAP in the past, but was recently made aware that GEE had Sentinel-1 data. Through investigation, I found that GEE allowed crop monitoring and other types of monitoring that relied on backscatter intensities, but did not find any information about ground movement tracking.

Does GEE allow for ground movement (InSAR) work?

Comment: GEE has only GRD data type of Sentinel-1. See this link. https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S1_GRD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. It is not possible to do any InSAR processing with Google Earth Engine, at least now. You might check ESAs geohazard TEP for cloud-based insar processing or COMET Services. (Also check this [link](https://twitter.com/mustuner2/status/1212977223843667968))
There are some more efficient/flexible python-based InSAR toolboxes. Might be of help.

[ISCE 3](https://github.com/isce-framework/isce3)

[LiCSBAS](https://github.com/yumorishita/LiCSBAS)

[MintPy](https://github.com/insarlab/MintPy)

[Pyrocko](https://pyrocko.org)

[PyRate](https://github.com/GeoscienceAustralia/PyRate)

[InSARFlow](https://github.com/levuvietphong/InSARFlow)